# Dialogflow: setFollowupEvent not working inside 'then'

Tags: javascript, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I made a chatbot which talks to an external API and calls another intent using the data provided by the API. The API provides the followup event's name. I have to make use of the inline editor only and not the webhook for certain reasons.

```
function setFollow(agent) {
  agent.add("hello"); 
  axios.post(url, body, {headers})
    .then (({ data }) => {
      agent.add("setting followup event");
      agent.setFollowupEvent({ "name": data.followupEventInput_name, "parameters" : { "name": data.name}});
    }) 
}
```

I am successfully calling the API and getting an appropriate response from it (the event name and the parameter value). The event and thus the next intent is still not being called. I even tried using hardcoded values to call the event but it did not work. The execution is going inside the `then` statement (checked with console logs) but the event is not being set (even  with hardcoded values).
What is the reason behind this and how can I solve it?

I have already checked the contexts: there are 2 active contexts (A and B) and the intent which should be called based on the event has 1 input context (A). Right now, no intent is being triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a JS issue. I was not returning the promise.

`return axios.post(url, body, {headers}).then(...)`
solved the issue.

This was happening because JavaScript code execution is asynchronous by default, which means that JavaScript won’t wait for a function to finish before executing the code below it. The return statement before the promise makes JS wait for the promise to `resolve` or `reject`.

Without the return statement, the function completed execution before agent.add() was executed and hence the Dialogflow bot was not working as expected.